# How to control SQL Server 2008 Express without SQL Server Management Studio (ssms)

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008-express

I Installed SQL Server 2008 Express on a client PC (I install SQL Server 2008 Express from Visual Studio Setup Version for C# program)

But I don't see SQL Server Management Studio icon in all programs windows.

Now if I want control tables and database in SQL Servers, how can I do this?

Comment: Is there some reason why you aren't installing management studio?

Comment: No, I install SqlServer2008Express From Setup Version of My Program (C# Program) And this Version Of sqlServer Doesn't Have ssms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just installing Sql Express on it's own will not give you any client tools.

If you have a full Sql Server (Dev or otherwise) already installed on the same client, the existing tools will allow you to manage the Express database instance too.  Otherwise, you wil need to install the version of Sql Express that comes with tools. This can be found here

[Sql Express with tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22973)